# Experiments and theory

Tags: experimental-physics, unified-theories

Sometimes when the data from experiments disagree with a theory which was supposed to describe the experiment we say:
"This theory works well for some range of variables but there are some exceptions".Why don't we try to make new theories which explain the exceptions of the previously accepted theory but are also compatible with previous theories in some level?Why when something new comes up which isnt explained by our current understanding do we add a note to the already existing theory?

Comment: "Why don't we..." we do.

Comment: What do you think general relativity is, for example? All the exceptions to newtonian gravity are explained using GR, while keeping newtons laws valid (at least in low energies and masses). Physics is all about that, but you just can't expect scientist to include the exceptions right away. You have to give them some time, because it is not that easy. If it were, physics would not be so exciting and interesting.

Answer (score 2):

> Sometimes when the data from experiments disagree with a theory which was supposed to describe the experiment we say: "This theory works well for some range of variables but there are some exceptions".Why don't we try to make new theories which explain the exceptions of the previously accepted theory but are also compatible with previous theories in some level?

We actually do both, and both are normal and necessary parts of science.

For example, when we learned Newton’s law of gravitation we began applying it to the solar system. Soon we saw that Uranus’ orbit disagreed with the predictions. Some theoretical calculations indicated that Uranus’ orbit could be “patched” to fit into the existing theories if we hypothesized the existence of a previously unknown planet. We looked and found Neptune, a discovery that was made by patching existing laws.

The opposite example occurred with Mercury which was also found to violate Newton’s law of gravitation. Since it had worked previously, we calculated where another planet would need to be to fit the data, and began searching for the planet Vulcan. No planet was ever found, and the discrepancy went unresolved until the development of General Relativity. Einstein’s theory of gravity agreed with Newton’s in the rest of the solar system, but naturally differed in the case of Mercury and explained the discrepancy.

So both approaches, patching existing theories and making new ones, are important parts of scientific progress. Neither are or should be used exclusively.

Comment: Shouldnt we just rewrite a theory from scratch when new data come in play?

Comment: @Jun Seo-He if we did then we wouldn’t have discovered Neptune. New data can also be wrong as in the case of the superluminal neutrino data, and looking for new theories can be wrong as in the case of the Pioneer anomaly. A blanket “rewrite a theory from scratch” policy would likely be harmful more often than it is helpful

Comment: But who decides when to begin from scratch and when to look for something we are missing?

Comment: Individual scientists. And different scientists can and do make different decisions about the same data.